# eclipse settings to maintain across multiple monitors

Tags: eclipse

I use eclipse either in laptop monitor itself or use external monitor. The external monitor supports till 1360 * 768 where as my laptop the setting is full HD. 
Whenever I move from laptop to external monitor the fonts look bulky and if I change the settings here in external monitor the font doesn't look good in laptop monitor.

Is there any way to export eclipse settings to a profile and then change to a particular profile according to environment ?

Comment: I am running eclipse on my laptop with external monitor connected via HDMI cable. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 haven't faced any problem.Add screenshots

Comment: Is the screen resolution same in both displays?

Comment: 1366x768 laptop 1920x1080 ext monitor